# How do I replace double quotes within csv fields but not add a trailing double quote to each line?

Tags: regex, csv, sed

I have a csv file named data_export_20130206-F.csv. It contains data that contains double quotes (") which is making it very messy to parse.

File looks kind of like this (but with more fields)

```
"stuff","zipcode"
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>","90210"
```

I want to "escape" the quotes that are within the fields so it will look like this (Note: the quotes within the xml have been doubled):

```
"stuff","zipcode"
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>","90210"
```

But when I run this:

```
cat data_export_20130206-F.csv| sed -E 's@([^,])(\")([^,])@\1""\3@g'
```

Unfortunately, It adds an additional double quote at the end of each line making the document invalid.

```
"stuff","zipcode""
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>","90210""
```

**How do I replace double quotes within csv fields but not add a trailing double quote to each line?**

Comment: I think that there may be trailing whitespace on those lines.  You should get rid of that first and then your `sed` should work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no trailing whitespace before the final `"` or else your replacement will match it.  You can use `sed` to trim trailing whitespace too:

```
sed 's/\s\+$//' x.csv | sed -E 's@([^,])(\")([^,])@\1""\3@g'
```

Comment: Also, this wipes out the $ which merges lines, can I keep the newlines?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just strip the extraneus double quote in a second pass:

```
sed -E 's@([^,])(\")([^,])@\1""\3@g' data_export_20130206-F.csv | sed 's,"\("$\),\1,'
```

or simply by squashing all the quote repetitions with `tr` (but this would break if any field would end with a quote):

```
sed -E 's@([^,])(\")([^,])@\1""\3@g' data_export_20130206-F.csv | tr -s '"'
```

If you still get newlines stripped for some reason, readd them on substitution:

```
sed -E 's@([^,])(\")([^,])@\1""\3@g' data_export_20130206-F.csv | sed 's,""$,"\n,'
```

Comment: this wipes out the $ which merges lines, can I keep the newlines?

Comment: Really? Mighty odd, what kind of sed do you have? I'll update the answer with a safer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fragile solution, but it works for the input you provided.

```
perl -pe 's/(?:^"|"(?=,)|"$|(?<=,)")//g;s/"/""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/(?:(?=,)|(?<=,))/"/g' FILENAME
```

Note commas within quotes will break this.
Given your input, the following output was produced.

```
"stuff","zipcode"
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>","90210"
```